# NSUnknownKeyException for a non-existent Core Data managed object property

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have an app that relies on `Core Data` for persistence.
The app is using `MVVM` architecture in order to facilitate testing.

The dev environment is a `MacBook Pro` (M1 Max) running `macOS 12.4` and `Xcode 14 beta 2`

So far everything has been working well until I attempted to add a new `entity` to my Model that had a relationship (many-to-one) to another entity. Attempting to instantiate one of these entities resulted in a `NSUnknownKeyException` associated with the property that defined the relationship, so I deleted this `relationship` from the model and re-ran the test.

Much to my surprise, the error `persisted` and I have been singularly unable to resolve it since despite the following:

- Clean build folder
- Delete derived data, reboot `XCode`
- Rename offending entity (error persists, just with the different `entity` name)
- Delete `entity` and add back into the Model
- Turn off code-gen and defined the MO subclass manually
- Check Core Data XML - this looks unremarkable and there are no residual properties that could be causing the problem
- Delete app from Simulator
- Erase settings then restart Simulator
- Uninstall and then re-install Xcode

The one thing I haven't tried yet is to run the code through Xcode 13 (it's a new machine so I was all enthusiastic and went straight for the `beta` which might have been a mistake!) so will be doing that shortly.

For now it seems that something relating to the `Core Data` model and relationships between entities is hiding out somewhere I can't find it but it could be a bug in the tooling. The problem of course is that I can't continue to develop the app with a compiler error I can't clear. Any thoughts or guidance would be very welcome...

**Xcode Model interface for Prescription**
[image: Prescription entity in model editor]

**Xcode Model interface for Procedure**
[image: Procedure entity in model editor]

**.xcdatamodeld XML for Prescription**
[image: Section of XML in .xcdatamodeld file related to Prescription entity]

**Error message during test**
[image: Error associated in Prescription object during testing]

**Extension on the offending ManagedObject subclass (convenience methods):**

```
extension Prescription {

    // MARK: - INTERNAL TYPES

    enum PointOfCareContext: String, CustomStringConvertible {

        case premedication, perioperative, postoperative, hospitalised



        var description: String {

            return self.rawValue.capitalized

        }

    }



    // MARK: - PROPERTIES

    var drug: Drug {

        get { guard let drug = cd_drug else {

            fatalError("Persistent store corrupted: Prescription is missing relationship to Drug.")

        }

            return drug

        }

        set { cd_drug = newValue }

    }

    

    var timePrescribed: Date {

        get { guard let timePrescribed = cd_timePrescribed else {

            fatalError("Persistent store corrupted: Prescription is missing timePrescribed.")

        }

            return timePrescribed

        }

        set { cd_timePrescribed = newValue }

    }





    /// When the drug should be administered

    /// Passing nil to this property indicates the drug should be given asap (so will return current Date)

    var timeScheduled: Date? {

        get { guard let timeScheduled = cd_timeScheduled else {

            return Date.now

        }

            return timeScheduled

        }

        set { cd_timeScheduled = newValue }

    }



    /// When the drug was administered

    /// Nil indicates not given yet

    var timeAdministered: Date? {

        get { return cd_timeAdministered }

        set { cd_timeScheduled = newValue }

    }



    var doseRate: Measurement<UnitDensity> {

        get {

            if (cd_doseRate != 0) {

                fatalError("Persistent store corrupted: Prescription doseRate == 0.")

            }

            return Measurement(value: cd_doseRate, unit: .milligramsPerKilogram)

        }

        set {

            cd_doseRate = newValue.converted(to: .milligramsPerKilogram).value

        }

    }



    var dose: Measurement<UnitMass> {

        get {

            return Measurement(value: cd_dose, unit: .milligrams)

        }

        set {

            cd_doseRate = newValue.converted(to: .milligrams).value

        }

    }



    var doseVolume: Measurement<UnitVolume> {

        get {

            return Measurement(value: cd_doseVolume, unit: .milliliters)

        }

        set {

            cd_doseVolume = newValue.converted(to: .milliliters).value

        }

    }



    var context: PointOfCareContext {

        get {

            guard let contextValue = cd_context, let context = PointOfCareContext(rawValue: contextValue) else {

                fatalError("Persistent store corrupted: Prescription has an invalid administration context [\(cd_context ?? "")]")

            }

            return context

        }

        set {

            cd_context = newValue.rawValue

        }

    }
```

**View Model that is the subject of the test:**

```
extension ProcedurePlanView {
    class ViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
        // swiftlint:disable:next nesting
        typealias Dependencies = HasParameterController & HasPersistence & HasViewFactory

        private let parameterController: ParameterController
        private let persistenceService: PersistenceService
        private let viewFactory: ViewFactory
        private let frc: NSFetchedResultsController<Prescription>

        let patient: Patient
        let procedure: Procedure

        // MARK: - TabOne conformance
        @Published var clinician: String = ""
        @Published var anaesthetist: String = ""
        @Published var assistant: String = ""
        @Published var history: String = ""
        @Published var tasks: String = ""
        @Published var complications: String = ""
        @Published var mucousMembraneColor: MucousMembraneColor?
        @Published var asaGrade: ASAGrade?
        @Published var cannulaPosition: CannulaPosition?
        @Published var cannulaSide: Side?
        @Published var cannulaGauge: PeripheralCannulaGauge?
        @Published var auscultation: String = ""
        @Published var temperament: Double?
        @Published var airwayType: AirwayType?
        @Published var airwaySize: String?
        @Published var airwayCuffStatus: Bool?
        @Published var breathingSystem: BreathingSystemType?
        @Published var prescriptions: [Prescription]?

        // MARK: - INIT
        init(procedure: Procedure? = nil, patient: Patient, dependencies: Dependencies) {
            self.persistenceService = dependencies.persistenceService
            self.parameterController = dependencies.parameterController
            self.viewFactory = dependencies.viewFactory

            var currentProcedure: Procedure?
            if let procedure {
                currentProcedure = procedure
            } else {
                currentProcedure = Procedure(context: persistenceService.viewContext)
                currentProcedure!.patient = patient
            }

            let frc = ProcedurePlanView.ViewModel.createPremedFRCUsing(
                patient,
                procedure: currentProcedure!,
                context: dependencies.persistenceService.viewContext
            )

            self.frc = frc
            self.patient = patient
            self.procedure = currentProcedure!
            self.prescriptions = ProcedurePlanView.ViewModel.performInitialFetchFor(frc)
            
            super.init()
            self.frc.delegate = self
        }

        // MARK: - PUBLIC METHODS
        func makeParameterGridView() -> some View {
            viewFactory.makeParameterGridView(patient: patient)
        }

        func resetForm() {
            clinician.removeAll()
            anaesthetist.removeAll()
            assistant.removeAll()
            history.removeAll()
            tasks.removeAll()
            complications.removeAll()

            mucousMembraneColor = nil
            asaGrade = nil
            cannulaPosition = nil
            cannulaSide = nil
            cannulaGauge = nil
            auscultation.removeAll()
            temperament = nil
            airwayType = nil
            airwaySize = nil
            airwayCuffStatus = nil
            breathingSystem = nil
        }

        func save() {
            procedure.patient = patient
            procedure.clinican = clinician
            procedure.anaesthetist = anaesthetist
            procedure.assistant = assistant
            procedure.history = history
            procedure.tasks = tasks
            procedure.complications = complications
            procedure.asaGrade = asaGrade
            Logger.viewModel.warning("Incomplete implementaton of cannula data in Procedure managed object and VM")

            _ = Observation.create(
                in: persistenceService.viewContext,
                patient: patient,
                parameter: parameterController.getParameterWith(name: .mucousMembraneColor),
                stringValue: mucousMembraneColor?.rawValue ?? "Unknown"
            )

            do {
                try persistenceService.viewContext.saveIfNeeded()
            } catch {
                fatalError(
                    "Unable to save context \(persistenceService.viewContext) to store due to error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                )
            }
        }
        
        // MARK: - PRIVATE METHODS
        private static func createPremedFRCUsing(_ patient: Patient, procedure: Procedure, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSFetchedResultsController<Prescription> {
            let request = Prescription.fetchRequest()
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "procedure == %@", procedure)
            request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Prescription.cd_drug?.cd_nameGeneric, ascending: false)]

            let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
                fetchRequest: request,
                managedObjectContext: context,
                sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                cacheName: nil
            )
            
            return frc
        }
        
        private static func performInitialFetchFor(_ frc: NSFetchedResultsController<Prescription>) -> [Prescription] {
            do {
                try frc.performFetch()
            } catch {
                Logger.persistenceService.critical(
                    "FRC failed to fetch Drugs from persistent store: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                )
            }

            return frc.fetchedObjects ?? []
        }

        // MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate conformance
        internal func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
            let newPrescriptions = controller.fetchedObjects as? [Prescription] ?? []
            prescriptions = newPrescriptions
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to clean build folder? I know you may have tried it, but it's not mentioned above & worth a try. Also, maybe show us what you're doing in `ProcedurePlanView.ViewModel`

Comment: Apologies - yes, that was the first thing I try when I get weird behaviour. Sadly that didn't help. I'll edit the post.

Comment: As an aside, the test doesn't actually touch/mutate the view model - the failure arrises when I attempt to add a new Prescription instance to the store by using one of the convenience methods. I've included the view model code anyway just in case there's some interaction I've missed...

Comment: Remove the app from the Simulator/device? And when you modify the model, you need a new version of the CoreDataModel, did you do that?

Comment: Good idea but no joy. Tried deleting the app manually from the simulator then a full simulator erase/reboot but the error persists (post updated)

Comment: This only fails for your unit test(s) and not when running the app?

Comment: Was starting with tests on the back end before building the production code so can't answer that one I'm afraid. I'll see if I can instantiate a Prescription in the mock store used for UI testing and report back

Comment: Quick and dirty implementation but it appears there are no problems when instantiating Prescription outside of the test scope. If I was to guess, there's some cached data that's private to the test target / bundle that's causing the problem but don't know where to look...